# System crashes when I press SHIFT+3

Tags: arch-linux, crash

I have arch linux installed and all packages were updated a few days ago.

Today, I discovered my system (possibly X Window) is crashing when I press SHIFT + 3. It does not happen when I press SHIFT+ALT+3.

It completely locks out and I have to pull the plug to get it to restart.

I can't find anything in the logs to tell me what happened.

`journalctl` shows nothing.

I am lost as to where to start looking for the problem.

I *assume* it occurred when I updated, but I updated so many packages, I wouldn't know which caused it.

Any suggestions please?

Edit: This is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a shortcut running a broken program. A few places you could look:

- Your desktop environment's keyboard shortcut manager.
- Your shell's shortcuts. For [Bash](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/b6d970a17cb0a99c5234214f8ccf702728c8ffdc/.bash_history#L50): `bind -P | grep --fixed-strings ' can be found on ' | perl -pe 's/((?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)\\C/\1Ctrl/g;s/((?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)\\e/\1Esc,/g'`
- Your graphics driver setup (for example `nvidia-settings`).

Comment: I checked all 3 and no sign of anything using that combination (or similar).